# How to properly integrate a CXF client into Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, cxf

I was looking at various ways how to build a SOAP client with CXF into a Spring Boot application. In particular I'm interested in configuring request/response logging.

Precondition: the CXF Maven plugin is used to generate Java stubs from the WSDL files.

I studied a number of tutorials [1][2][3] and they all do that slightly differently. The question is whether there's an "officially endorsed" way of integrating a CXF client with Spring Boot. The CXF documentation doesn't seem to say.

**Option 1: BindingProvider**

The existing code I'm working with (not mine) does it like that:

```
@Bean
public PartnerServicePortType partnerServicePortType() {
  PartnerServicePortType partnerServicePortType = new PartnerServiceV0().getPartnerService();
  configureService((BindingProvider) partnerServicePortType, Services.PARTNER_SERVICE.serviceName());
  return partnerServicePortType;
}

private void configureService(BindingProvider bindingProvider, String path) {
  bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, baseUrl + path);
  if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
    bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, username);
    bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, password);
  }

  /* add logging interceptors
  Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(bindingProvider);
  Endpoint cxfEndpoint = client.getEndpoint();

  cxfEndpoint.getInInterceptors().add(new PayloadExtractingLoggingInInterceptor());
  cxfEndpoint.getInFaultInterceptors().add(new PayloadExtractingLoggingInInterceptor());
  cxfEndpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(new PayloadExtractingLoggingOutInterceptor());
  cxfEndpoint.getOutFaultInterceptors().add(new PayloadExtractingLoggingOutInterceptor());
  */
}
```

`PartnerServiceV0` is generated class that extends `javax.xml.ws.Service` and looks like this:

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "PartnerService_v0", 
                  wsdlLocation = "classpath:some.wsdl",
                  targetNamespace = "urn:some-namespace") 
public class PartnerServiceV0 extends Service {
```

As you can see I added the code to enable request/response logging to the `configureServcie` method. While this *does* work it feels somewhat odd that we'd have to go through all of that for every service.

**Option 2: JaxWsProxyFactoryBean**

For verification purposes I ported the above code to using `JaxWsProxyFactoryBeans`:

```
@Bean(name = "partnerService")
public PartnerServicePortType generateProxy() {

  JaxWsProxyFactoryBean proxyFactory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
  proxyFactory.setServiceClass(PartnerServicePortType.class);
  proxyFactory.setAddress(baseUrl + Services.PARTNER_SERVICE.serviceName());
  if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
    proxyFactory.setUsername(username);
    proxyFactory.setPassword(password);
  }
  return (PartnerServicePortType) proxyFactory.create();
}
```

Adding logging config is something I'd still have to figure out with this strategy.

**Tutorials I checked**

1. https://blog.codecentric.de/2016/07/spring-boot-apache-cxf-logging-monitoring-logback-elasticsearch-logstash-kibana/
2. http://www.baeldung.com/apache-cxf-with-spring
3. http://www.littlebigextra.com/consume-secure-soap-web-service-spring-boot-application/

Answer (score 3):

You can directly use `JaxWsProxyFactoryBean` to set logging interceptors or directly use logging features as shown below.

```
    @Bean
    public HelloWorld bus(SpringBus bus) {
        JaxWsProxyFactoryBean bean = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
        bean.setServiceClass(HelloWorld.class);
        bean.setAddress(serverUrl);
        bean.setBus(bus);
        //bean.setInInterceptors(Collections.singletonList(new LoggingInInterceptor()));
        bean.setFeatures(Collections.singletonList(new LoggingFeature()));
        return bean.create(HelloWorld.class);
    }
```

[Here](https://github.com/kprasad99/kp-soap-ws-client) is complete example.

Answer (score 1):

I using some jax-ws web service with cxf like this code

```
package org.roshan.framework.config;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManager;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;

import org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.TLSClientParameters;
import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client;
import org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit;
import org.roshan.framework.config.PaymentProperties.WebServiceDetail.SSL;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader;

import com.tosan.modern.epayment.webservice.merchant.paymentservice.TosanIPGWS;
import com.tosan.modern.yaghut.service.SoapServices;


@Configuration
public class WebServiceClient {

    @Inject
    private PaymentProperties paymentProperties;

    @Autowired
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    @Bean(name = "PaymentWebService")
    public TosanIPGWS PaymentWebServiceCLient() throws MalformedURLException {

        JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
        factory.setServiceClass(TosanIPGWS.class);
        factory.setAddress(paymentProperties.getShaparak().getWsPublicUrl());

        TosanIPGWS service = (TosanIPGWS) factory.create();
        try {
            final Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(service);
            // client.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
            // client.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
            setupSsl((HTTPConduit) client.getConduit(), paymentProperties.getShaparak().getSsl());
        } catch (Exception e) {
//          System.out.println("PaymentWebServiceCLient v9898989898");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return service;
    }



    private void setupSsl(HTTPConduit httpConduit, SSL ssl) throws Exception {

        final String keyStoreLoc = ssl.getKeyStore();
        final String keyPassword = ssl.getKeyStorePassword();
        final String keystoreType = ssl.getKeyStoreType();
        final String trustStoreLoc = ssl.getTrustStore();
        final String trustStorePassword = ssl.getTrustStorePassword();
        final String trustStoreType = ssl.getTrustStoreType();

        final TLSClientParameters tlsCP = new TLSClientParameters();

        tlsCP.setDisableCNCheck(true);

        if (ssl.getKeyStore() != null && !ssl.getKeyStore().isEmpty()) {
            final KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keystoreType);
            Resource resource1 = resourceLoader.getResource(keyStoreLoc);
            keyStore.load(resource1.getInputStream(), keyPassword.toCharArray());
            final KeyManager[] myKeyManagers = getKeyManagers(keyStore, keyPassword);
            tlsCP.setKeyManagers(myKeyManagers);
        }

        if (ssl.getTrustStore() != null && !ssl.getTrustStore().isEmpty()) {
            final KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(trustStoreType);
            Resource resource2 = resourceLoader.getResource(trustStoreLoc);
            trustStore.load(resource2.getInputStream(), trustStorePassword.toCharArray());
            final TrustManager[] myTrustStoreKeyManagers = getTrustManagers(trustStore);
            tlsCP.setTrustManagers(myTrustStoreKeyManagers);
        }

        httpConduit.setTlsClientParameters(tlsCP);
    }

    private static TrustManager[] getTrustManagers(KeyStore trustStore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {
        String alg = KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory fac = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(alg);
        fac.init(trustStore);
        return fac.getTrustManagers();
    }

    private static KeyManager[] getKeyManagers(KeyStore keyStore, String keyPassword) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        String alg = KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        char[] keyPass = keyPassword != null ? keyPassword.toCharArray() : null;
        KeyManagerFactory fac = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(alg);
        fac.init(keyStore, keyPass);
        return fac.getKeyManagers();
    }

}
```

Comment: That's essentially what I did in my option 1.

Comment: @MarcelStör Did you find the answer to your question?